# Github clone error RPC filed HTTP 408 how to sovle this?

Tags: github

I remove this project folder before finding this error message.

now I want to clone this project again.

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/hive.git

Cloning into 'hive'...
 error: RPC failed; HTTP 408 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 408
fatal: error reading section header 'shallow-info'
```

How to fix this issue, I need help. thx you

successfully clone the repository

Comment: Did you try `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`?

Comment: Yes, I try the command lines "git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000 " but this still  error: RPC failed; HTTP 408 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 408
fatal: error reading section header 'shallow-info'

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 408 is a Request Timeout.  That usually means that your client was too slow at actually making a request, and so the server timed out the request to free resources.

Normally, if your Internet connection is even moderately fast, this should never occur.  It might happen if you have a proxy or TLS MITM device, including a non-default antivirus or firewall.  If so, try completely removing such software and rebooting, or switching to a different network without that proxy.

If you want to try troubleshooting more, you can run your command preceded with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1` (under Git Bash on Windows or a POSIX shell on Unix) to see what's happening when you're connecting.

Note that [the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) explains what `http.postBuffer` does and why it should never be needed.  It also has no effect on clones or fetches, and thus only serves to waste large amounts of memory in this case.